# Rails: Byebug doesn't print in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, byebug

From some unknown reasons, Byebug stops printing code in console.

For example, I've added *byebug* in following test:

[image]

What I've got in console / terminal:

[image]

Do you have any idea what could be wrong or where could I search for a reason of this problem?

EDIT:

Command how I run tests:

```
$ rake spec
```

EDIT 2:

When I run server with Byebug in any place it also doesn't work. It even doesn't print any logs. This is how does it look console after running server and sending to them some requests - ... empty:

[image]

That does it doesn't print in console could be caused by puma.rb configuration:

```
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch('RAILS_MIN_THREADS') { 5 }.to_i
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch('RAILS_MAX_THREADS') { 5 }.to_i
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

bind "unix:///var/run/puma.sock?umask=0000"

stdout_redirect "/var/log/puma.stdout.log", "/var/log/puma.stderr.log", true

environment ENV.fetch('RAILS_ENV') { 'development' }

plugin :tmp_restart
```

Comment: In the screen shot you have added i observed that there are 17 examples and in the Spec it's only one. can you recheck which spec you are running, and update the question how you are running the spec?

Comment: I've added edit how I run tests. There is a 17 unit tests, for each it works in the same wrong way. When I run server with byebug at any place, it also doesn't work.

Comment: try by running like this `bundle exec rspec model/spec_name.rb`

Comment: Thanks! it works! Moreover, it starts also work with my previous attempts. Maybe bundle exec something restarts.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: Please copypaste the text, do not post screenshots.